# Zoom image jQuery

Tags: jquery, zooming

I am using a zoom image jQuery script on my page. It works fine when I have to show one image but fails of course when I have 3 different images injected in my mark up. I want to know how can I edit my script so I can use the referenced jQuery script multiple times on my page.

The html and binding script is as follows

```
<div id="zoomcontainer">
<div class="zoomapp" id="zoomapp"> <img id="imgRecord" class="jqzoom" src="/demo-image.jpg"/>
 <div id="zoomerNav"> <a id="btn_up" href="#"></a> <a id="btn_dn" href="#"></a> <a id="btn_left" href="#"></a> <a id="btn_right" href="#"></a> <a id="btn_plus" href="#"></a> <a id="btn_minus" href="#"></a> <a id="btn_home" href="#"></a> </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
                        $(function () {
                            $('#imgRecord')
                        .grViewer({ zoomLimit: 2, renderScale: 0.5 })
                        .bind('load', function () { $('#zoomapp').css('background', $('#zoomapp').css('backgroundColor')); });
                        });
                    </script>
```

Comment: instead of `#imgRecord` (ID) try to use `.imgRecord` (CLASS)

Comment: That was my first attempt to fix but didn't work that's why I posted this. I was hoping it will be easy as that.

Comment: Cannot tell from what you posted what .grViewer really is.

Comment: The grViewer script is referenced from here http://www.genesreunited.co.uk/_resources/scripts/jQueryExtensions/jquery.jqzoom.js.ashx?mfs=1

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps:

```
$(function () {
    $('.imgRecord').each(function(){
        $(this)
            .grViewer({ zoomLimit: 2, renderScale: 0.5 })
            .bind('load', function () { $('#zoomapp').css('background', $('#zoomapp').css('backgroundColor')); }); 
    });
});
```